# expand source block from different org file

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I followed the example here [noweb reference syntax](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html) to successfully replicate expansion of source code blocks. However when I move one source block into a different org file, the expansion comes up empty. Here's a minimal example to demonstrate:

File 1: a.org

```
#+begin_src python :noweb yes
<<b.org:code-expansion>>
#+end_src
```

File 2: b.org

```
* python code expansion with :noweb-ref
 :PROPERTIES:
 :header-args: :noweb-ref code-expansion
 :END:

** code block 1
#+begin_src python
print("hello")
print("there")
#+end_src

** code block 2
#+begin_src python
print("now or forever")
#+end_src
```

Expanding source code block (in a.org) with `org-babel-expand-src-block` comes up empty. I confirmed when all code snippets are in one file, code expansion works as desired. Also, code **execution** works when code blocks reside in different files.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, it only works within a single file. And glancing through the linked page, I don't see any mention of it working across files. Have you any evidence that it should?

Comment: nothing concrete in org mode documentation stating expansion would work across files. The indirect evidence is extrapolating from code execution, as mentioned in my original post.

Comment: You mean I can do `C-c C-c` on the code block in `a.org` and get `hello\nthere\now or forever\n` as the result of that code execution? If so, I cannot reproduce that result: I get an error without a `:results` header (i.e. with the default `:results value`) and nothing with `:results output`.